# Why was my C# question closed when similar Java questions remain open?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions

See the question below from Stack Overflow:

> [Can I say C# is a 100% Object
> Oriented Programming Language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356464/can-i-say-c-is-a-100-object-oriented-programming-language-closed)

Some users closed my question within 1 hour. What's wrong with my question?
See some other questions similar to my question below, where both the questions and their answers got up-votes.

> [Is Java fully object-oriented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054662/is-java-fully-object-oriented)
>
> [Is java 100% object oriented ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974583/is-java-100-object-oriented)

Please tell me:

1. How might I write a valid, effective question?
2. Which types of questions can I ask here?
3. What's wrong with me?

Thanks to all...

Comment: You can say whatever you want. You can say C# is the greatest programming language in the world. You can *say* you're the queen of New Zealand and everything you touch turns into gumdrops... You can say, "Abracadabrazimbledroppydo!" Being able to say something and saying something meaningful are two very different things... Never the less, I've voted to close those other two questions as well.

Comment: Nothing is "wrong with you", please don't take it personally. :-) Standards of what sort of subjective questions are acceptable have risen, even since January, and those other questions would probably also be closed if asked today — especially if they started with "Can I say…".

Comment: Anyway, by highlighting those questions you've got the first merged into the second and the second on three close votes, so there's a good chance neither will be open by the time I've finished typing this comment.

Comment: @Shog *I could say* that you're overreacting to chanchal's use of the English language.

Comment: @Jon: you *could* say that, or you could just edit the title to make me look foolish...

Comment: `You can say, "Abracadabrazimbledroppydo!"`. Well now I have to change my password again

Comment: I can perhaps see why the Java Qs have now been [closed] because they aren't directly related to a particular programming query and are in the _normal_ StackOverflow section. However, @chanchal1987's question is in the Community Wiki and it is programming related, so why close it?!

Comment: It just happened the opposite to me:
I filled this question that has been downvoted:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145786/what-are-the-top-java-ee-design-flaws
While there is a similar C# question that has been too much upvoted:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411906/c-net-design-flaws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), in particular:

> ### What kind of questions should I not ask here?
>
> Avoid asking questions that are
> subjective, argumentative, or require
> extended discussion. This is not a
> discussion board, this is a place for
> questions that can be answered!

Comment: So what is the deference between my question and other's questions I listed with this question?

Comment: @chanchal1987 - the difference is when the question was asked and who looked at it.  Each person with sufficient privileges can vote to close.  Obviously each person uses a different standard and views a different subset of questions.  The fact that one question gets closed and another doesn't isn't, in itself, proof that either question is acceptable or unacceptable.  Personally, I think it's an interesting, if not particularly practical question and don't have any problem leaving it open in CW mode.

Comment: As @tvanfosson says, it was asked as part of the Community Wiki - isn't that what the CW is for? Personally I think it is an interesting programming _related_ question suitable for the community wiki.